# Run AWS CLI commands on AWS Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I'm trying to set up a function on Lambda AWS that can run AWS CLI commands. I can use nodejs and java but not sure if Lambda has aws cli installed. Usually I could use the SDK in nodejs or java programs.

Edit: My question really is, is there a way to schedule Lambda to send some string to an EC2 instance?

Answer (score 1):

In node and python the aws sdk is pre-installed and you can schedule any lambda function using the console.

Answer (score 0):

If it is about Scheduling Support which you are looking for then AWS Lambda's Feature list now support - Scheduling. This was released along with Python Language Support, Version Support during [re:Invent 2015](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-update-python-vpc-increased-function-duration-scheduling-and-more/).

The Scheduling support work with very simple configuration like UNIX cron configuration.

[image]